# maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, divide-and-conquer

Started learning python, this is maximum sum subarray i have tried. Ending up with "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison". My algorithm seems ok to me. Please help me if im doing anything wrong.

```
import sys
import math
def maxtuple(lss,rss):
    if lss[2] > rss[2]:
        return lss
    else:
        return rss
def crosssubarray(A, start, mid, end):
    ls=rs=-sys.maxsize
    maxleft=0
    maxright=0
    sum = 0;
    for i in reversed(range(start, mid)):
        sum = sum + A[i]
        print(i)
        if sum > ls:
            ls = sum
            maxleft = i
    sum = 0
    for i in range(mid+1, end):
        sum = sum+ A[i]
        if sum > rs:
            rs = sum
            maxright = i
    return (maxleft, maxright, ls+rs)

def maxsubarray(A,start,end):
    if start == end:
        return (start,end,A[start])
    else:
        mid = (start+end)/2
        lss = maxsubarray(A, start, mid)
        rss = maxsubarray(A, mid+1, end)
        css = crosssubarray(A, start, mid, end)
        maxsub = maxtuple(lss,rss)
        maxall = maxtuple(maxsub, css)
        return maxall

A = [13,-3,-25,20,-3,-16,-23,18,20,-7,12,-5,-22,15,-4,7]
print(maxsubarray(A,0,15))
```

Comment: Works for me (once the indents are fixed).

Comment: what is the output value you are getting?

Comment: What output are you trying to get? You must show us your expected output for this question to be complete.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in this function:

```
def maxsubarray(A,start,end):
    if start == end:
        return (start,end,A[start])
    else:
        mid = (start+end)/2
        lss = maxsubarray(A, start, mid)
        rss = maxsubarray(A, mid+1, end)
        css = crosssubarray(A, start, mid, end)
        maxsub = maxtuple(lss,rss)
        maxall = maxtuple(maxsub, css)
        return maxall
```

To be precise, the first 5 lines. The reason for "working" (don't know your expected result) in python 2.x is because `/` is for floor division, while in python 3.x `/` is for float point division. And thanks to float point round-off error, `start` is mostly likely never going to be equal to `end`.

---

If integer floor division is what you're going for, you can replace the `/` to a `//`.

Doing so, the error will disappear and returns `(8, 10, 32)`

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the stack depth allowed - with this, deeper recursive calls will be possible, like this:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) # 10000 is an example, try with different values
```

... But I'd advise you to first try to optimize your code, for instance, using iteration instead of recursion.